# Deleting Object from Object navigator in Oracle reports 11g

Tags: oracle, object, oracle11g, oraclereports

I have an object called B_19 which I am not able to find in "paper layout".
The object is a "Text_Field" and I would like to delete the object.
Is there a way to find, where it is located or Is there an option to delete from Object Navigator?

Comment: To ask the obvious: did you  - in Object navigator - click that field and pressed the DEL key?

Comment: Yes I did.It just deleted the name not the object :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm going to say can't fit a comment. I'm answering to this:

> Yes I did.It just deleted the name not the object

That's strange. I'm on 10g, though, and tried to do the same: in

- Object navigator's Paper Layout > Main section > Body > R_1 frame
- I clicked B_10 fields,
- pressed the DEL key on the keyboard
- Reports asks "Delete/close the object(s) selected?"
- Saying "Yes" deletes it from both Paper Layout editor and Object navigator.

Unfortunately, unlike Forms, we can't resize a field in its Property Inspector (and make it large enough to be seen in the Layout Editor) ...

**However**, if you edit (with Notepad or any other text editor) the .RDF file and search for that field (for example, B_10 in my report), you'll see something like this:

```
        <text name="B_10">
          <textSettings justify="center"/>
          <geometryInfo x="9.37679" y="19.09868" width="8.31236"
           height="0.37052"/>
          <textSegment>
            <font face="Arial" size="8"/>
            <string>
            <![CDATA[(potpis ovlaštene osobe)]]>
            </string>
          </textSegment>
        </text>
```

See the `geometryInfo`; it shows field's location. Width and height are, in your case, probably 0 (zero). See if you can "select" it in Layout Editor (knowing its location) and delete it.

---

Another option is to save that report as a JSP file. Edit it (in Notepad), search for `B_10` and **delete the whole `<text> ... </text>` section**. If you open the .JSP in Reports Builder, that field will be gone.

Note that it works only for .JSP; won't work for .RDF files (I know, I tried it).

---

Hopefully, something of the above will help you get rid of that field. Good luck!